# Django - Add Object associated to another

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I tried customizing a Django poll tutorial.

I gave options so that users can add questions and options themselves.

'Choice' object from my models.py seems to be tricky.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='choices')
    option = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.option
```

Choice object is one-to-one relation with the Question. When I end values through the below HTML page, it doesn't create a new Choice.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add Member</h1>

<form action = 'addoptrecord/' method='post'>

    {% csrf_token %}

    Choice: <br>
    <input name='ch'>
    <br>
    Vote: <br>
    <input name='vo'>
    <br>

    <label for="optquestions">Choose a Question:</label><br>
    <select name="optquestions" id="optquestions">
    {% for question in questions %}
    <option value={{question.id}}>{{question}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select><br><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Not sure about the right syntax/method to associate the Choice data with Question while adding through views.py

```
def addoptrecord(request,optquestions):
    ch = request.POST.get('ch')
    vo = request.POST.get('vo')
    que = Question.objects.get(id=optquestions)

    pollopt = Choice(que,option=ch,vote=vo)
    pollopt.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

The above operation throws me an Integrity Error.

```
IntegrityError at /addopt/addoptrecord/
NOT NULL constraint failed: pollsapp_question.question
```

UPDATE: Adding my template file - addopt.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add Member</h1>

<form action = 'addoptrecord/' method='post'>

    {% csrf_token %}

    Choice: <br>
    <input name='ch'>
    <br>
    Vote: <br>
    <input type = 'number' name='vo'>
    <br>

    <label for="optquestions">Choose a Question:</label><br>
    <select name="optquestions" id="optquestions">
    {% for question in questions %}
    <option value={{question.id}}>{{question}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select><br><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, You have to specify the field question in your Choice constructor. And your question id is send via POST data, so you have to retrieve in same ways of previous fields:

```
def addoptrecord(request,optquestions):
    ch = request.POST.get('ch')
    vo = request.POST.get('vo')
    optquestions = request.POST.get('optquestions')
    que = Question.objects.get(id=optquestions)

    pollopt = Choice(
        question=que,
        option=ch,
        vote=vo
    )
    pollopt.save()
    return redirect("index")
```

Comment: More simplify it using `return redirect("index")` ;)

Comment: I'm actually going to change that

Comment: I made the changes above. I noticed that I simply forgot to do it. Thanks for pointing it out. However, it still throws me the error. 

IntegrityError at /addopt/addoptrecord/
NOT NULL constraint failed: pollsapp_question.question

pollque 
Error in formatting: TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
queue  - None
request <WSGIRequest: POST '/addopt/addoptrecord/'>

Any Suggestions?

Comment: you do not post the urls, so i suppose you can remove second argument of my function based view, firstly. Next, you have to check if `<option value={{question.id}}>{{question}}</option>`  has value set

Comment: @LucasGrugru - Removed the 2nd argument in view and also posted the template above. Same error :(

Added the entire code on Git - https://github.com/sasidharan7/Django/tree/main/polls

Comment: i tried your code, but i do not understand, the stack trace show it is not the good function was called, you do not see it ? You urls is not good, `addquerecord/` and `addoptrecord/` are associated to the same view. You have to read the stack trace, the error often is easely foundable

Comment: Thanks, @LucasGrugru. It's working now. It's a silly careless mistake and I spent many hours on solving it. Thanks again for efforts on checking the code too.